# 'Lift' sites show a brief blank page in Chrome

Tags: scala, lift

Any site I see generated with the Lift framework displays strange behaviour in the Chrome browser - on page load, the browser tab is blanked for around 1/3 of a second before the page is displayed.  It's very disconcerting.  This behaviour does not appear on Firefox or IE, just Chrome.   In IE and Chrome, there is a slight delay after requesting a page during which the old page remains visible, which is the expected behaviour.

The behaviour is visible in Chrome even in the Lift homepage:

http://liftweb.net/

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Seems that Symfony 1.4 has the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be blank until style.css is loaded, from what I gather from the developer tools in Chrome itself. In the audit, it says style.css should be moved to head, but it is already there. I wonder if the `<content>` tags that enclose everything are causing problems?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just starting out with Lift.  I guess one fix would be to embed the style sheet.  Is that easy to do with Lift?

Comment: @Crosbie Well, that's the thing. As far as I can see, Lift _is_ generating correct code. It seems to be a bug on Chrome side, but that's really far outside my own expertize.